# How to get custom python packages to ignore contents of local directory and rely on contents of installation directory?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-packaging

I created a package that we'll say is `hello_world`. The main file is `hello_world.py`:

```
import hello_moon

def hello_world():
  print(hello_moon.say_hello())
```

where it imports `hello_moon` as another file in the same directory:

```
def say_hello():
  print("hello moon")
```

Then I install this: put both files in a `build/lib` directory, write a (minimal) setup.py, and an `__init__` file (which just contains `from hello_world import hello_world`), and install with `python setup.py install`.

Everything works well -- I can go to another directory (say, `blah`) and run it successfully:

```
> cd blah
> python
>> import hello_world
>> hello_world.hello_world()
```

The problem arises if I create a file called `hello_moon.py` in that `blah` directory. In this case, everything breaks -- it looks at my local `hello_moon.py` rather than the original one.

This is making me NUTS. I thought the whole point of installing packages was to separate the package's behavior from the local environment. How do I get this to work, without resorting to renaming either or both instances of `hello_moon.py`?

Comment: I once had a similar experience, on confusing directories. I was installing packages in Rpi using pip. I found that if I use ***python 3, I must use pip3***. If I use pip, then package goes to pip 2 directories, and later python 3 won't find it. Of course you might not be using Rpi pip and python, but I guess the problem is generic. A horrible thing is that if you use pip and not pip3 in the very beginning, then Rpi won't let change later (I did struggle for hours! and later learned the os "bug" from experts). The remedy is to refresh a new SD card. Good luck and happy programming. Cheers.

Comment: Thanks. In this case there is no pip at all -- I wrote and installed the package in question myself. I'm guessing I need to add some magic to my `__init__.py` or `setup.py` to get the package to act as a "compiled object" rather than a collection of scripts.

Comment: Yes, setting sort of an "environment" for python, which is too hard for me. BTW, if you are using Rpi, you might like to try the Thonny IDE, which is very helpful in debugging, much more helpful then IDLE or CLI debuggers. Cheers.

Comment: If you successfully find anything with an unqualified `import hello_moon`, then it’s *not* in a package at all.  It’s true that Python’s love for the current working directory ja a bit silly, but you haven’t built what you think you’ve built.

Comment: I agree I'm doing something wrong :-). But `import hello_moon` in a random directory does fail, as it should. Further, `hello_world` can call `hello_moon` no problem. The only issue arises when I create a blank file called `hello_moon.py` in the local directory -- then all of it sudden, `hello_world` fails, because it tries to run the local script.

Comment: This is the normal behavior. The current working directory is always (almost always?), the first place where Python looks for importable modules or packages. So Python will pick up the `hello_moon` from the current working directory over any other one (the one installed).